# Powershell Get-AzureAdUser: Authorization_RequestDenied , message : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation (since October 2022)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

**Context**
This question has been asked many times already, but I think this is a special case of Microsoft disabling APIs on newly created app registrations.

I use the (soon to be deprecated) AzureAD module and the included Get-AzureADUser in a context, where I cannot easily switch to the AZ.Connect- Module.

**How I got there**
Last month I registered an app in my development tenant and gave it the permissions

*Microsoft Graph*

- User.Read.All
- User.ReadWrite.All

Everything works: Get-AzureADUser can be called by the powershell script using that app.

Today I registered another app in the same tenant. I used the exact same settings and the exact same permissions. But whenever trying this app registration in the powershell script I get the message:

> Error occurred while executing GetUsers
> Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
> Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

As soon as I switch back to the "older" app registration it works.

Connect-AZAccount and Get-AzADUser work with both apps, so the issue is not the privileges I think.

**Question**
Is there any way to make the "new" registration work until I am able to update the code to use the newer modules?

**Bonus questions** (optional):
Can someone confirm that it is not possible with a newly registered app to use the AzureAD module anymore?
Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution together with a colleague of mine: By applying the *legacy* "Azure Active Directory Graph" permissions you are able to still use the "old" commands even with new apps.

These permissions are "greyed out" in the Dialog under "Microsoft API" with the comment:

> Azure Active Directory Graph will be deprecated in June 2022. We recommend using Microsoft Graph APIs for your application. If you are currently using Azure Active Directory Graph, please migrate to Microsoft Graph

But they can still be selected using the "APIs my organization uses" tab by typing "Windows Azure Active Directory" or the Application (Client) ID "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000".

For using Get-AzureADUser you need the "Directory.Read.All" role, to use "Set-AzureADUser" you need the "Directory.ReadWrite.All" role assigned as type "application".

This is how it looks after assignment:

[image: Role assignment]